# salience detection in images in android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, computer-vision

hi guys i want to extract the most salient part of the image. for this purpose i want to use salient detector algorithm in java, and i want this to implement on a bitmap image. Let me tell u some thing that i cant use openCV for this so please help me to archive these with simple algorithms.
Here is the kind of thing what i want..[image: sample]

i have tried sobel filter first but that doesnt gave me this kind of result, by the way em talking only about salience part other result should not be considered.
thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously sobel filter wont give you results like that. It is an edge detector algorithm and not an algorithm for saliency detection. 
Salient object in an image is that part of the image where all the human attention goes and rest part is mostly ignored by the vision of humans.

There are different kinds of saliency that you should study before implementing, like "Interest Points", "Class specific saliency" and  "Generic Saliency". In my opinion, you are looking for "Generic Saliency".

You can try the saliency toolbox by Itti et. al., iNVT
Some other saliency detection algorithms include:

- HZ07 and HZ08 by Hou and Zhang
- BITS system by Klein and Frintrop
- AIM model by Bruce and Tsotos
- CoDi Saliency

I think CoDi saliency is the fastest algorithm, compared to above mentioned algorithms and will be suitable for mobile application.

I dont think anyone here in SO is going to implement that for you. Study the paper and use opencv for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java implementation for the Stentiford model within LIRE: [SVN source code](https://code.google.com/p/lire/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/net/semanticmetadata/lire/imageanalysis/visualattention/StentifordModel.java)

It's for visual attention, but all in all it's the thing you mean with saliency. It's the most basic and simple model but it's easy to implement and rather fast. It should pose not too much of a problem to transfer it to Java for Android. The name of the research paper is given in the source. An example can be found here: [visual attention in LIRE](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/2010/03/22/visual-attention-in-lire/)

The basic approach is to check how often a texture re-occurs in an image. The assumption is that the more often the texture re-occurs, the less attention it gets by viewers. It's based on random pixel comparisons, so it's non deterministic, but still leads to acceptable results, ie. for an energy function for image re-targeting.

Comment: I tried the aforementioned method and although it worked it was rather slow: ~ 3 sec for an average image 350x500 pxls